# Oracle date transformation

Tags: oracle9i

how to change the date format for example, the data in the database as input  represent, 01-jan-10 but how do i get an output as 01-jan-2010. And there are some dates which are 01-dec-99, which are to be represented as 01-dec-1999.. How can this be done?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can date format with TO_CHAR like :`TO_CHAR(<YOUR_DATE_COLUMN>, 'DD-MON-RRRR')`

e.g:

```
SELECT TO_CHAR(SYSDATE-5000, 'DD-MON-RRRR') MYDATE FROM DUAL
UNION
SELECT TO_CHAR(SYSDATE, 'DD-MON-RRRR') MYDATE FROM DUAL
```

Comment: but how to figure  if it is 01-jan-1999 or 01-jan-2099??

Comment: DATE is stored in the Oracle in its internal format. What you see in output is the format specified by the NLS setting. When you use the format I specified DB will show it appropriately i.e. 1999 or 2099 depending on what is stored.

Comment: Try the construct first you will understand.